# get email attachment with imap but getting different results whether email is sent from Outlook Client or by Web

Tags: python, email, outlook, attachment

I wrote a python script (or copied from a tutorial) to get values from a email attachment.
Every day, I get an email from my energy provider with the data of the production of my solar power plant. If I run the script when the original email comes in, I get some gibberish back (but the CSV is not corrupt, I can read it manually by opening the file). When I forward the email from my Outlook 2016 Client again to myself, this email delivers the expected values.

If I run following script with the original email from my energy provider and one email forwarded to myself I get this:

```
================================ RESTART ================================

Email ID: 3

09.01.2020-13.01.2020_1.csv found and processing
['MDE6MDA7MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDE6MTU7MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDE6', 'MzA7MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDE6NDU7MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDI6MDA7', 'MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDI6MTU7MC4wMDANCjEwLjAxLjIwMjA7MDI6MzA7MC4w']

Email ID: 5

09.01.2020-13.01.2020_1.csv found and processing

['09.01.2020;11:15;16.500', '09.01.2020;11:30;16.100', '09.01.2020;11:45;17.700']

=========================================================================
```

Where Email ID: 3 is the original email and Email ID 5: is the forwarded.

Is there some decoding which is going on at my Outlook and so my script can read it afterwards?

```
try:
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993') #IMAP PORT 993
    mail.login(config.EMAIL, config.PASSWORD)
    mail.select('inbox')

    head, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
    longest_csv = 0

    for email_id in range(first_email_id, latest_email_id+1):
        try:
            typ, data = mail.fetch(str(email_id), '(RFC822)') 
            raw_email = data[0][1]

            # converts byte literal to string removing b''
            raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

            #download attachments
            for part in msg.walk():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                    continue
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    continue
                fileName = part.get_filename()
                if '.csv' in fileName:
                    print('Email ID:',email_id)
                    print(fileName[14:len(fileName)],'found and processing')
                    fileData = part.get_payload().split('\r\n')
                    print(fileData[50:53]) # Show 3 lines out of ~500
                    print()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    mail.close()         
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: You're disregarding the specified content-transfer-encoding of that body part. The gibberish you see is simply the base64-encoded version of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the majority of the cases, attachments are base64 encoded when send by email.
Thus, in your line
`fileData = part.get_payload().split('\r\n')` you are simply getting the content of the attachment, which is base64 encoded.

You might want to try to decode it first. To do this you should first `import base64`, and then do something like

```
fileData = part.get_payload()
fileData = base64.b64decode(fileData)
```

Now you should have stored inside `fileData` the actual content, which you can then proceed to `.split('\r\n')`

Comment: An upvote or marking as solution would deff help :)

Comment: I did, this message appeared: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Marking it as a solution (that green check sign below the arrows) should do the trick